# How to install Bio.Subsmat package in python using google colab? ineed to use MatrixInfo

Tags: python, installation, biopython

I need to work with MatrixInfo in google colab using python, I do not know how to install it, but so far I try several ways:

```
!pip install Bio.SubsMat
from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo
```

as well

```
!pip install Bio
from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo
```

I know is dumb but I also tried:

```
!pip install SubsMat
from SubsMat import MatrixInfo
```

Anyone knows the proper way to install this? The idea is to use MatrixInfo following a notebook from Kaggle.

Comment: Your second example should be close.  Does `from Bio import SubsMat` work?  You can then use `SubsMat.MatrixInfo`.

Comment: from Bio import SubsMat 

cannot import name 'SubsMat' from 'Bio' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Bio/__init__.py)
 it does not work

Comment: What about `import Bio.SubsMat.MatrixInfo as MatrixInfo`?  I realize I'm kind of stabbing in the dark here.

Comment: No module named 'Bio.SubsMat'  when try "import Bio.SubsMat.MatrixInfo as MatrixInfo", !pip install Bio works well, but from there i do not know how to get MatrixInfo

Answer (score 2):

In the notes for [Biopython 1.75 (from Nov 2019)](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/8d9d20d09c6ee2a672c8477e890f0ab4e9e48825/NEWS.rst#6-november-2019-biopython-175), it states:

> A new module substitution_matrices was added to Bio.Align, which includes an Array class that can be used as a substitution matrix. As the Array class is a subclass of a numpy array, mathematical operations can be applied to it directly, and C code that makes use of substitution matrices can directly access the numerical values stored in the substitution matrices. This module is intended as a replacement of Bio.SubsMat, which is currently unmaintained.

Currently it does not appear that the SubsMat submodule is installed when you install Biopython. Thus, you get your error! To fix this, try to use the substitution_matrices module in Bio.Align.

Comment: Alternatively, you could install Biopython 1.78, which still includes Bio.SubsMat

Comment: It worked for me with Biopython 1.78